# Button clicked reset the dropdown selector

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a selector like this:

```
<select ng-model="type">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

and a button:

```
    <div class="btn action-btn" onclick="$ctrl.doSomething()">
        Reset
    </div>
```

I'm thinking how can it be made that when the button is clicked the selector to be reset to value 1 no matter which one is selected.

I guess that there must be a function to be called which must be implemented in the controller, but the selector is not connected to the controller so I don't know how that function can change the value of the selector.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are u using `Angularjs` ?

Comment: `ng-click="type=1"`

Comment: _but the selector is not connected to the controller_ what do you mean by that ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey possibly that `onclick` doesn't do anything, and he needed `ng-click` instead

Comment: if the above code is in the same file and you are using angular then @AlekseySolovey suggestion should work. you done need any controller here. both the button and select  is in the same file and you bild ng-model with select. so they both got the same scope

Comment: Did you checked my solution?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `ng-click` and set the model value inside the click event

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.doSomething = function() {
     $scope.type = '1';
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select ng-model="type">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<div class="btn action-btn" ng-click="doSomething()">
        Reset
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see that your example is working but doesn't work in my case, don't know why. Here is a part of my code, maybe it is easier: https://pastebin.com/p0ZskdGr

Comment: @LeoMessi try using ng-model="$ctrl.type" and tell me whether that works or not.

Comment: it resets the selector but the data on the table is frozen, nothing happens there..

Comment: this is the tr of the table: `<tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.alertsResponse | orderBy:$ctrl.sort.active:$ctrl.sort.descending | filter: {Type:type} track by $index">`

Comment: @LeoMessi Please post a question with an exact problem. This seems to be a related funcationality.

Comment: Maybe this is more clear: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49915875/reset-selector-does-not-reset-the-table-data-properly